# Apacite with natbibapa option change "and" in the references with ampersand

Tags: cross-referencing, apacite

I am using apacite with natbibapa option `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` in my latex document. At the moment, when I use `\cite`, the authors are delimited by "and". I want that to be changed to `\&` instead.

For example, I want to go from this referencing style:

`Gilfoil and Jobs (2012)` to  `Gilfoil & Jobs (2012)`

I looked at this question: [Using “and” instead of ampersand in natbib in-text citations (“\citet”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186631/using-and-instead-of-ampersand-in-natbib-in-text-citations-citet) but this questions is only about the natbib package and is the opposite of what I want.

Any ideas of where to look? I also searched the documentation on apacite here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf but did not find something related to my question

Comment: Just to mention: This is standard APA behaviour. `\cite` without any pre- or postnotes is just `\citet` and gives *Name (Year)*, whereas `\citep` gives *(Name Year)*. For the former citation style, where the name is outside the parentheses the APA wants "and" between the names, for the latter, when the names are inside the parentheses, the APA wants "&". See https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/02/changes-parentheses-bring.html and https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/01/writing-in-text-citations-in-apa-style.html.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that if you use `apacite` chances are you want to follow APA style and APA style wants it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delimiter between the two names is saved in the two `apacite` macros `\BBAA` and `\BBAB`. Their default definitions are

```
\newcommand{\BBAA}{\&}  % between authors in parenthetical cites and ref. list
\newcommand{\BBAB}{and} % between authors in in-text citation
```

You can redefine them as you see fit. But you have to do that in `\AtBeginDocument` since `apacite` reacts to the document language and changes those settings in `\AtBeginDocument`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\BBAB}{\&}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby and James Hacker},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\citet{appleby} \citep{appleby}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Appleby & Hacker (1980)]

Comment: Thank you for the example and the knowledge you provided. I am indeed following the APA style. That was really helpful.